# Python Search a .txt file and when a match is found print a number of lines after the matching word

Tags: python

Im looking to search a file and when the word im looking for has been found i want it to print the 8 lines below that word. Keep in mind im a complete noob and ive only been doing this for a few weeks. This is what i have but it doesn't work (obviously!):

```
name = input("What did you put as the calculation name?: ")
saved_calcs = open("saved_calcs.txt", "r")
lines = saved_calcs.read()
i = lines.index(name)
for line in lines[i-0:i+9]:
    print (line)
saved_calcs.close()
```

Comment: You might want `lines = saved_calc.readlines()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if your input exactly matches the content in a line from the file, the code could be something like this:

```
name = input("What did you put as the calculation name?: ")
saved_calcs = open("saved_calcs.txt", "r")
lines = saved_calcs.read()
split_lines = lines.split("\n")
index = split_lines.index(str(name))+1
for line in split_lines[index:index+8]:
    print line
saved_calcs.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

lines.index will look for a line that is exactly name.
You need to go through the lines and search for your string.

```
i = -1
for x, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.find(name) != -1:
        i = x
        break
....
```